# How can I automatically archive an HTML file using a bash script?

Tags: html, bash

I have two directories: `main/` and `archive/`.
In `main/`, I have a **.html** file.

Whenever I change this file, I want a *Bash script* to:

1. automatically **copy** and **move** the file from `main/` to `archive/`
2. and renames it to the current date (Example: `Sep2,2018.html`).

If this is possible, how can achieve this?

Comment: Yes.  But SO is not a free code writing service.  Have you tried anything?  See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I'm not asking for a writing service, I'm asking if there is any way to do it because I am lost. I have tried copy and paste commands, which work fine, but I don't know how to rename the newly copied file to the date as mentioned in my post.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to do that what you are asking for. However, you can create a bash script to copy the html file to archive after renaming it. And then you can run that script in crontab at every 5 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on Linux you can [use `inotifywait` to learn about new files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24955/3645) and move them immediately.

Adding the date to the file name is a completely separate issue which must have been answered at least a dozen times on [unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=file%20add%20date).

Comment: Is there any way I could get the inotify-tools package on mac, or is it just a linux thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to move files after 30 mins

```
find /main/ -maxdepth 1 -mmin -20 -type f -exec mv "{}" /archive/ \;
```

You can adjust the `-mmin -20` to whatever duration that you think is good for your

What basically the command does is, it tries to find files in the current folder -maxdepth 1 that were last modified 30 mins ago -mmin -30 and move them to the target directory specified. If you want to use the time the file was last accessed use -amin -30.

More info can be found here: [Move files that are 30 minutes old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37411988/move-files-that-are-30-minutes-old)

You can also try this tool which is good
https://superuser.com/questions/678191/copy-new-files-from-a-monitored-folder-to-another-in-debian

Comment: Thank you for answering, but is there a way I could move the file instantly after, say, editing it? Does this work on macOS?

Comment: Yes you can. This should work on mac as the command find works on osx.

Comment: Ok, then how can I make it move a file after editing it?

Comment: When you adjust the -mmin to a duration, it will automatically move the file to that duration.